# Flutter app crashes for iOS build on startup

Tags: android, ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

I am working on the application, where it was working in a proper manner. but later I did update the mac to macOS Monterey 12.2.1 and updated my iPhone device to latest 15.2 and Xcode 13.0 and used the latest one 13.2.1. But now the application runs crashes on startup or even after login with but there is which is driving me crazy.

Point is it does not work when building on xcode and it works fine when running from Android studio. So below are my specs that I am working on:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/username/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (3 months ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.0)
    • Xcode at /Users/username/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at /Users/neosoft/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.34.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.51
```

[image: Image for error on xcode]

I have been using the Firebase Firestore as a data store. What can I try next?

Comment: can you delete podfile.lock and pods folder in ios folder, and then you must run (pod cache clean --all & pod install --repo-update) in flutter terminal iOS directory,after that you must run or build again your flutter code. after that feedback to me.

Comment: I have done that before its seems the problem still remains

Comment: I had the same issue while back with one of my projects, for my case the application was crashing due to the font being not supported in ios and in an other case the third party package I was using was causing the crash . The crash may be caused by multiple reasons from any one of your packages not supporting the latest version or mismatch in flutter version. when u updated your system.

Comment: Sorry cannot share the project, Its from on of my clients

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar: it's not bad to ask for a public repo, but if the question needs one in order to be understood, it is off-topic and would need to be put on hold. So, it is generally best to help the question author improve the question without that if possible.

Comment: @Sagar, this error is for pod installation, when you run the flutter project, it installs all features as pod packages in the iOs app, you must be accurate to install pod from flutter correctly, so you must clear All pods cache and delete pods folder and all things depends on pod after that you must upgrade your cocoa and install or run your flutter app.

Answer (score 9):

For the most cases, the final solution for me was always deleting the whole ios folder (make sure to backup the logo, assets, ...), running `flutter create -i swift .`  to recreate the ios folder, and running `flutter clean`.

Every time I face the error, I did those steps several times in a random order, and it just got solved.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me, even though it was one of the higher labour solution.

Answer (score 8):

After some reading I found out that in my case it was probably this issue:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60657

So I made a workaround for the issue by changing the build scheme to production one in case I need to have a build that works without debugger attached to the running application. (e.g. so my colleagues can test the app)

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Comment: I use the same technique. - Just run the app in the 'Release' build configuration. - that's it. - it works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

Inside iOS > AppDelegate.swift, add the FirebaseApp.configure() method before  GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

```
 FirebaseApp.configure()
 GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

**Alternatively:**

1. Run `flutter clean`
2. Navigate to the ios folder then delete the pods folder.
3. From your terminal command `cd ios` , then run $pod install
4. Once complete, right-click ios > Open in Xcode.
5. From the application window top menu bar, click Product > Clean Build Folder
6. Build the project (Product > Build)
7. From your project terminal command `flutter run`

Comment: I have error : can not find FirebaseApp in scope

Comment: Solution for issue faced by @Kobi - Don't forget to add `import Firebase` on top if you're putting `FirebaseApp.configure()`.

Comment: For the aternative solution mentioned above, run `flutter pub get` before the 3rd point.

Comment: I found the problem, it was request for location permission in the iOS initialization

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 14+, debug mode Flutter apps can only be
launched from Flutter tooling, IDEs with Flutter
plugins or from Xcode.

Alternatively, build in profile or release modes to
enable launching from the home screen.

[Maybe because the flutter doesn't show you this text, you think it's a mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvmI7.png)

Or maybe `rm -rf Podfile.lock` then `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

Please take a backup of the project, delete `pubSpec.lock`,  and from inside the ios folder delete 'Podfile.lock', `pods` directory and Xcworkspace. Then run `flutter pub get` then navigate to ios folder and run `pod install`. Then try building it in xcode.

Comment: Sorry for the delay did try it but still no luck

Comment: In pubspec.yaml for firebase core give version as any, then run flutter pub get. Then try building it from Android studio or vs code directly. You may get better insights of the error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like while building it takes reference from derive data for ios.
Follow bellow steps hopefully, this will work

1. Delete `Derive data` for ios
2. Delete `podfile.lock`
3. Execute `flutter clean` to your project terminal
4. Execute `flutter pub get`
5. Move to ios directory and execute `pod install`

Then try to build from Xcode.

Comment: Sorry for the delay i was downgrading the macOS to bigsur so that it might work. But i did try this thing its still not working

Comment: Try removing the plugin version of Firebase Firestore or make it `any` this will download a compatible version of SDK and run it from Flutter code, maybe this will help you!