# Flutter can't find firebase-sdk: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Since a few days my flutter project (which worked perfectly in the past) is unable to run in the iOS Simulator. I get the same Error-Message in VS-Code in any other project as well:

```
Exception: Unable to get Xcode project
information:
2022-04-03 13:02:39.310
xcodebuild[13948:96964] Requested but did not
find extension point with identifier
Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications
for extension
Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS 
of plug-in
com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-04-03 13:02:39.314
xcodebuild[13948:96964] Requested but did not
find extension point with identifier
Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier
for extension
Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.
watchOS of plug-in
com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package
dependencies:
Couldn’t fetch updates from remote
repositories:
fatal: cannot change to
'/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xco
de/DerivedData/Runner-gqpjmwwezhlcmzblkhpf
xhqqwwhf/SourcePackages/repositories/fireb
ase-ios-sdk-c63c6384': No such file or
directory
```

At first I'm really confused because of the part about the watchOS-Error, because I'm not using watchOs in any of my projects.

Second is the main problem: Flutter or Xcode can't find the Firebase-SDK, which was correctly installed with the instructions from firebase-website.

I already tried the following steps:

- update macOS, Flutter and Xcode to newest versions
- flutter doctor does not find any problems
- tried it on different flutter projects
- removed the pod file.lock and loaded a new one
- updated all pods (pod repo update, pod install, etc.)
- on other platforms the project works fine (Chrome or Android)

I really hope anyone can help me with the Error-Message, already spend several days fixing the error but it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like Swift Package Manager may have been used with the project which I don't believe is compatible with Flutter.

Comment: I installed the Firebase SDK in Xcode (but im not sure if it was the Swift package manager), is there another way to install the sdk to the flutter project directly to avoid the error? I just used the instructions from firebase website.

Comment: can you share your pub yaml(flutter package manager) file? this error is for pods, the firebase doesn't install correctly. check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71351351/flutter-app-crashes-for-ios-build-on-startup/71453545#71453545

Comment: if it doesn't work, you must go to iOS folder in terminal(console), and delete the pods folder and podlock file, after that run the below command 'pod install', you can see the error in consol log.

Comment: For using Firebase with Flutter, follow the Flutter instructions instead of the Firebase instructions. The last I checked, Flutter did not support installing from Xcode with Swift Package Manager.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien your suggestion was correct. I deleted the whole iOS folder and create a new one without initializing firebase via Xcode. Now it is working. Thanks for the hint!